# Multiple select structure in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, select, structure, multiple-tables

Can anyone please explain two questions below in regard to the structure and syntax?

1: Why would the first block be alright, but the second one has the error 1060 for duplicate column name FD_ID? How can I fix it?

```
SELECT * from(
(SELECT a.FD_ID as id, aa,bb from
(select FD_ID, NT_VALUE as aa from nutrition_amount where nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 203) as a left join
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as bb from nutrition_amount where nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 204) as b on a.FD_ID = b.FD_ID) as ab left join
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as cc from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 205) AS c on ab. id = c. FD_ID)


SELECT distinct * from(
(select * from
(select FD_ID, NT_VALUE as aa from nutrition_amount where nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 203) as a left join
(select FD_ID, NT_VALUE as bb from nutrition_amount where nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 204) as b on a.FD_ID = b.FD_ID) as ab left join
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as cc from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 205) AS c on ab. id = c. FD_ID)
```

2: I was trying to build up the multiple structure to 10 different FD_ID. Is this structure usable to do it? Insights, please :)  / any better solutions to deal with this kind of problem?

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * from(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * from(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * from(
(select a.FD_ID as id, aa,bb from
(select FD_ID, NT_VALUE as aa from nutrition_amount where nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 203) as a left join
(select FD_ID, NT_VALUE as bb from nutrition_amount where nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 204) as b on a.FD_ID = b.FD_ID) as ab left join
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as cc from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 205) AS c on ab. id = c. FD_ID) AS bc left join 
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as dd from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 208)  AS d on bc. id = d. FD_ID) AS cd left join 
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as ee from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 269) AS e on cd. id = e. FD_ID) AS de left join
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as ff from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 291) AS f on de. id = f. FD_ID) AS ef left join 
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as gg from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 303) AS g on ef. id = g. FD_ID) AS fg left join
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as hh from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 307) AS h on fg. id = h. FD_ID) AS hi left join
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as ii from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 605) AS i on hi. id = i. FD_ID) AS ij left join
(SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE as jj from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount. NT_ID = 606) AS j on ij. id = j. FD_ID)
```

The given error is 1064 from line 7.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: give all of these: `FD_ID` aliases, and the problem will likely go away

Comment: Just tried that, but the it didn't work. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
SELECT FD_ID, NT_VALUE 
FROM nutrition_amount 
WHERE NT_ID IN (203, 204, ..., 606);
```

and do the rest on application level, for whatever reason you want to have your data horizontal. A database is there to store and get the data **in an efficient manner**, nothing else. It's **not** there, to format your data nicely. Do this elsewhere, if you must.

Comment: However, the database I am working on requires me to do it horizontally... I tried this one and came out an applicable idea for my need, haha :)  Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from (
(select FD_ID as iq, NT_VALUE as aa from nutrition_amount where nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 205) as a left join
(select FD_ID as iw, NT_VALUE as bb from nutrition_amount where nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 204) as b on a.iq = b.iw left join
(SELECT FD_ID as ie, NT_VALUE as cc from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 203) AS c on b.iw = c.ie left join 
(SELECT FD_ID as ir, NT_VALUE as dd from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 208) AS d on c.ie = d.ir left join 
(SELECT FD_ID as it, NT_VALUE as ee from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 269) AS e on d.ir = e.it left join
(SELECT FD_ID as iy, NT_VALUE as ff from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 291) AS f on e.it = f.iy left join 
(SELECT FD_ID as iu, NT_VALUE as gg from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 303) AS g on f.iy = g.iu left join
(SELECT FD_ID as ii, NT_VALUE as hh from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 307) AS h on g.iu = h.ii left join
(SELECT FD_ID as ip, NT_VALUE as ii from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 605) AS i on h.ii = i.ip left join
(SELECT FD_ID as ia, NT_VALUE as jj from nutrition_amount WHERE nutrition_amount.NT_ID = 606) AS j on i.ip = j.ia );
```